# openCv-python unable to read images in vs code

Tags: python, image, opencv

am just a new Buddy to the world of coding, however, today i happen to face an annoying problem with running an openCv python scripts in vs code which was perfectly running two days ago. I have never modified the code since a created it and it is running in spider without any problem.

the following is the error message popping up:

```
(base) E:\UDEMY>C:/Users/ProBook/Anaconda3/python.exe e:/UDEMY/openCV/cvimg.py
<class 'NoneType'>
None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:/UDEMY/openCV/cvimg.py", line 7, in <module>
    print(img.shape) # print the dimanstion of the image interms of pixel
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'

(base) E:\UDEMY
```

Since the program is running through spider, i assume the problem lies in vs code

Below is the python script:
"""

```
import cv2

img=cv2.imread("mycastle.jpg",1) #load the image

print(type(img)) #check the data type of image 
print(img) # print the matrix array of the image
print(img.shape) # print the dimanstion of the image interms of pixel
print(img.ndim) # checks the dimention of the image 2D or 3D etc

resized_img=cv2.resize(img,(800,768))
cv2.imshow("mycastle", resized_img)
cv2.imwrite("myNewCastle.jpg", resized_img)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

"""

[exact image i was using.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BFT9.jpg)

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: Your problem is that the image is `None`, which happens when you read an image from a path that doesn't exist---so the problem is how you've specified the filename, likely. Give it the absolute path instead of relative, or run vscode/spyder from the same directory to get the same treatment of relative paths.

Comment: use the fullpath of mycastle.jpg

Comment: @alkasm, thanks for the information.. actually i created the same file using VS code and both the script and the image are saved in the same directory, hence both spider and VS code are getting the same treatment of the relative path

Comment: It doesn't matter where the code is saved, it matters where it's *ran from*; paths aren't relative to your script's directory, they are relative to the current working directory. Use `pathlib.Path` and check that the path `.exists()` first, then cast it to a string to read it. Like this does: https://github.com/alkasm/cvtools/blob/master/cvtools/imgio.py#L5

Comment: Thanks for the guidance, upon trials and restarting vscode now everything works as required

Answer (score 0):

The code works fine in my machine, so I will assume your image path is invalid. Try moving the code below to line 4. Does the image appear?

```
cv2.imshow("mycastle", img)
```

Comment: @O Yahya , i have tried your directive but still its not working.. Did you use VC code to run the code?, because the same program is also perfectly running for me when i try it in spider but fails in VC code

Answer (score 0):

You must specify your image path. Go to your image, right click on it and in properties there is path something like "C:\Users\images\6.JPG". change "\" with double "\" and try it again.

```
img=cv2.imread("C:\\Users\\images\\mycastle.jpg",1)
```